# ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'nosetests') not found

Tags: python, powershell, nosetests

I am trying to launch the nosetests by following the instruction from the [learnpythonthehardway](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html) tutorial.

I tried to run the nosetests form Powershell and got the following:

```
PS E:\python\projects\skeleton> nosetests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\nosetests-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('nose==1.3.0', 'console_scripts', 'nosetests')()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 343, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.45-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2353, in load_entry_point
    raise ImportError("Entry point %r not found" % ((group,name),))
ImportError: Entry point ('console_scripts', 'nosetests') not found
```

Comment: Does it work from regular command-line (cmd)?

Comment: It yielded the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but for anyone else who runs into this problem try running

```
sudo pip uninstall nosetests
pip uninstall nosetests
```

Then reinstall nosetests regularly. 
If it still doesn't work try searching your laptop through finder for any other instances of nosetests and getting rid of those as well. 
If that still doesn't work clear your trash bin as well. T

Answer (score 0):

After hours of banging my head against my keyboard with the same issue, I finally have it working on my end.

Your question isn't clear about your setup, but I had the same error message (Import Error... entry point console scripts not found).

I was using pip to create my package, then at some point (months ago) switched to poetry. My poetry toml file didn't have the packages installed, nor the entry point!

Poetry add-ing the packages and adding this got it working for me:
[tool.poetry.scripts]
myCli = "myCli.main:cli"

I had a setup.py, but editing it won't do anything since setup.py is created during the build process.